# Adobe Dreamweaver CC freezing on start up

Tags: dreamweaver

I just installed Adobe Dreamweaver CC through Creative Cloud and everytime I open it up the program freezes and goes black. However, Photoshop opens perfectly. I'm wondering am I the only one having this problem?

Comment: OS? System Specs? Have you Rebooted? Install location correct? Any Processes Running the could cause problems?

Comment: I'm on Windows 7. I haven't rebooted. I used Creative Cloud to install the program. and I am not sure.

Comment: Reboot. Try to find an install that doesn't require a "middle man" application.

Comment: For folks still looking for the answer, the reg edit below works. The other answers don't work for shit.

Answer (score 6):

Same thing happened to me after it run great for a long time. My solution was to run Dreamweaver as administrator and it loads up fine now (Windows 8.1 64bit).

Comment: This is working for me. Was crashing on startup and closing. Now works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I've had used MS's ProcessMonitor tool to see what's going on while Dreamweaver stuck at "Initializing Assets" screen.

And what I discovered is that DW generates millions of queries to registry key **HKCU\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Dreamweaver CC 2015\Temp File List**.

Over the time Dreamweaver accumulates here thousands empty entries like **pathXXX** and infinitely loop over them when starting.

So, removing all this entries makes DW start in 3 seconds.

And no need to remove site cache, winfilecache etc.

Comment: After struggeling with this problem for years, finally a solution that works. And to be clear, to do this you click windows search icon (on Win10) and write regedit and start that program that comes up. Then when regedit has started you expand the folder HKEY_CURRENT_USER (thats what HKCU stands for in Levon's post) and then open the path in the post above and mark all the "path-files" and delete them.

Answer (score 3):

i've just get on this error now...
and solved it by deleting registry key

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Dreamweaver CC 2015
```

you can also delete this folder just in case the problem still exist..

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Dreamweaver CC 2015
```

n:
this steps will delete configuration and preferences..
but your sites will still there...

Answer (score 3):

Okay here is my solution that worked for me, delete the Configuration folder in

```
C:\Users\Your Name\AppData\Roaming\Adobe
```

Since `AppData` is a hidden folder you will very likely have to hit the windows button, and type in `%appdata%` to access the folder. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I was having a problem with Dreamweaver (CC 2017) hanging (grey screen) during loading the site cache.

After it hung I had to kill all the Dreamweaver processes in the task manager.  Clicking the X to close the window didn't completely kill Dreamweaver.

I then just deleted the contents of the cache folder.
   goto this directory and delete the contents, making path substitutions for your username, dreamweaver version and language.
   c:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Dreamweaver (your version)\en_US\Configuration\SiteCache

When I restarted Dreamweaver it reloaded the site cache and everything worked again.

Answer (score 2):

Dreamweaver does this thing where it checks for changed or moved links when first starting one of your sites in the right panel.  It will do this same thing when you first start the program (because you typically leave the most recent site still open) but will not give you the popup option to "stop" this process like it does when manually switching them.  This is why it freezes on that gray screen.  None of the other solutions will prevent it from doing this except on the first time you deleted one of the suggested files and open Dreamweaver.

My solution was to create a new site and simply call it "!NONE" pointed at a local empty folder.  Then, before closing my Dreamweaver, after working, I would switch to that site.  Now when I open Dreamweaver later, it opens almost instantly because it is checking a folder with nothing in it.

Comment: You are absolutely right, but in case you stuck for some reason with a site that is not blank and have lots of links in it, copy paste the site you were working on and leave the file that dreamweaver reads blank and it will start without trouble. I tested it and it works perfect!!!

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me.

I followed the instructions at: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/494811 .

I ended up needing to rename the Configuration folder and let the program recreate the folder when starting up next time (this can take a while if you have large sites as cache needs to be recreated). It then opened with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

My Dreamweaver is hanging on start up but if I turn off wifi / internet it works OK!